# Moderncv: Place picture next to a section on the right

Tags: moderncv, cv

I'm struggling to place a picture next to `\cvline`'s in a section. It always displays on top of the `\cvline` text. I have space on the right where I want to place my profile picture. Can you guys tell me how to do that?

```
\cvline{Name}{Name}
\cvline{Vorname}{Othername}
\cvline{Anschrift}{bblabla}
\cvline{Telefon}{12431412}
\cvline{E-Mail}{d@gmail.com}
\cvline{Geburtsdatum}{asdfasdf}
\cvline{Geburtsort}{asdfasdf}
\cvline{Staatsangehörigkeit}{asdfasdf}
\raisebox{-1.9cm}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth]{example.jpg}}\\[2.5em]
```

[image: Code and Visuals]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) instead

Comment: Welcome. // Please always start at \documentclass and end at \end{document}. Leave out, what's not needed to show your problem.

Comment: Might be easier to come up with something if we had a full document; short of that I can only suggest something like `\smash{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\raisebox{0.5cm}{\includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{example.jpg}}}}`
changing the value of the raisebox to whatever you want to control the vertical placement.